# How can I generate an Avaya CMS report to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, avaya

I want to automate the extraction of an Avaya cms report to Excel,

How do I do it using VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that Avaya generate for us a VBA script, I wrote a small python script that changes the parameters in the avaya VBA script to update the Day and the file name & path for a schedule extraction.

Comment: does it login automatically or it need to login to CMS first then run the script ?